# open_basedir restriction cant set to none, plesk cpanel

Tags: apache, php, plesk, vhosts, open-basedir

I got Plesk on a dedicated server. I had `open_basedir restriction in effect` error in my PHP website, so i have edited the php.ini files in server root and also created one within each domain.

In php.ini file the `open_basedir` is set to `none`.

`safe mode` is set to off.

**Problem:**

None of the changes i made in php.ini take effect on site, i still get the open_basedir error. I restarted apache and the server via plesk (10.3) cpanel.

it looks like my changes are overridden some where else, but don't know where?

I also created vhost.conf file within each domain, this don't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any `.ini` files in your `phpinfo();` output you've overlooked?

Comment: BTW [according to this](http://www.uk-cheapest.co.uk/blog/2011/09/how-to-disable-plesk-open_basedir-restriction-in-effect/), Plesk requires you to rebuild its configuration...

Comment: @Wrikken yes i looked at all php.ini files. but will try second option.. but surly rebooting the server should fix that.

Comment: I gather apache doesn't so much read _that_ file, but a rebuild will incorporate the file in its config. Why Plesk does this is beyond me, I've binned working with it 5 years ago and never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a bug in Plesk 10.3 for Linux. There was a bug in Plesk for Windows, and it has been fixed at 11.0 http://kb.parallels.com/115269

Possibly that bug for Linux is also fixed in 10.4 or in 11.0 versions.